# Redraw CoreGraphics drawing when device orientation changed

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I working on app where I want to make custom shape button like this below

[image]

for this I'm using coregraphics to draw that shape for button and here code of button

class RewardStepsButton: UIButton {

```
@IBInspectable var firstStep: Bool = true{
    didSet{
        if firstStep{
            secondStep = false
            thirdStep = false
        }
    }
}
@IBInspectable var secondStep: Bool = false{
    didSet{
        if secondStep{
            firstStep = false
            thirdStep = false
        }
    }
}
@IBInspectable var thirdStep: Bool = false{
    didSet{
        if thirdStep{
            firstStep = false
            secondStep = false
        }
    }
}
@IBInspectable var buttonColor: UIColor = UIColor.lightGray
// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
    
    
    
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let btnLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    if firstStep{
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 5, y: 5), radius: 5, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width - 15, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width - 15, y: self.bounds.height))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: 5, y: self.bounds.height - 5), radius: 5, startAngle: .pi / 2, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
        path.close()
    }else if secondStep{
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width - 15, y: 0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width - 15, y: self.bounds.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 15, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    }else{
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width - 5, y: 5), radius: 5, startAngle: 3 * .pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width - 5, y: self.bounds.height - 5), radius: 5, startAngle: 2 * .pi, endAngle:.pi / 2, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.height))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 15, y: self.bounds.height / 2))
        path.close()
    }

    btnLayer.path = path.cgPath
    btnLayer.fillColor = self.buttonColor.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(btnLayer)
    self.bringSubviewToFront(self.titleLabel!)
    if thirdStep || secondStep{
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 25, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }else{
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
    
}
```

}

now it works almost perfect when I run the application buttons draw on app same as I want see below
[image]

now the problem it that when I changed the orientation of device, shape of drawing button is same doesn't refresh.

[image]

so I googled it and try to find solution and lot of answer were use
setNeedsDisplay() method for this so I use that method also but problem is, it draw another shape or add another layer and not erase the previous one. see this

**When app load**

[image]

**when landscape orientation**

[image]

**when again portrait**

[image]

please give me solution or idea how to solve this mess, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont add `layer` in `draw()` method as in calls every time you call `setNeedsLayout` or `layoutifNeeded`   ... use to add them in common `init()`

```
self.layer.addSublayer(btnLayer)
```

remove this line from `draw()` method

```
//MARK:- initializers
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
 
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

    private func commonInit(){
        
         self.layer.addSublayer(btnLayer) 
        
    }
```